# Importing long rows to Cassandra from Spark

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, datastax

I've been trying to use the datastax spark-cassandra connector (https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) to import some data from csv files. I understand that most of the time case classes can be used on the import, but I'm dealing with rows with about 500 fields and so I can't use them without nesting (due to the 22 field limit on cases). It's also possible to directly store a map, but I don't think this is ideal either since there are several data types.

I may be missing something in the conversion from RDD[String] -> RDD[(String, String, ...)] Since a .split(",") just yields RDD[Array[String]].

I've done a fair amount of searching without much luck, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do something like this:

1. Read your text file (or whatever file format)
2. Use `.map( ..)` to convert each line into an `Array[Any]` (or a `Map[String,Any]`)
3. Two options here

   - Convert each `Array[Any]` into `CassandraRow`. A `CassandraRow` is just `columnNames:Array[String]` and `columnValues:Array[Any]` and then write the `RDD[CassandraRow]`
   - Implement a `RowWriterFactory[Array[Any]]` and write the `RDD[Array[Any]]` using the custom `RowWriterFactory`. Look at `CassandraRowWriter`'s code.